# This just shows a blank black screen, and if I do not put glutSwapBuffers() in both places it shows a blank white screen?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

When I compile it, it makes a blank blac screen, if I take out glut swap buffers from either location, or both at the same time I get a blank white screen, whats the problem?

```
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#else
#include <GL/glut.h>
#endif

#include <stdlib.h>



 void ProcessSpecialKeys(int key, int x, int y){

    switch(key){

       case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT:

exit(0);

       case GLUT_KEY_LEFT:

exit(0);

       case GLUT_KEY_UP:

exit(0);

       case GLUT_KEY_DOWN:

exit(0);

       default:

exit(0);

    }

}




void renderPrimitive(void){

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f,0.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f,-1.0f,0.0f);
    glEnd();
}

void display(void){

    glTranslatef(0.0f,0.0f,-0.5f);
    renderPrimitive();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
glutInitWindowSize(320,320);
glutCreateWindow("Dimension");
glutDisplayFunc(display);

    glLoadIdentity();

    glutSpecialFunc(ProcessSpecialKeys);

glutMainLoop();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: [How is this question different from your other question?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17730333/i-am-new-to-glut-and-it-is-just-rendering-a-blank-white-screen-help-please)

Comment: I only see one call to `glutSwapBuffers()` . . .

Comment: I can't see any setup of the modelview & projection matrices. It's quite likely the quad is rendered behind the camera. Set up your camera and projection using e.g. `gluLookAt()` and `gluPerspective()`.

Comment: Sorry it didnt copy right its at the end of my renderPirimative function as well.

Answer (score 0):

Before you start a new draw, you need to clear the buffer. In other words, do this in your display function:

```
void display(void){
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); // <-----
    glTranslatef(0.0f,0.0f,-0.5f);
    renderPrimitive();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

and read about the function [glClearColor](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glClearColor.xml)

**EDITED**:

That's not the right place, but to change the background color, do this:

```
void display(void){
    glClearColor(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); // <-----
    glScalef(0.5f,0.5f,0.5f);  // Your Quad is taking all the framebuffer
    renderPrimitive();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Comment: Yet it still will not work...

Answer (score 0):

Try glColor3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f); And remove glClearColor(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1);